# Refactoring code that imports a csv file that has headers

Tags: ruby, oop, polymorphism, switch-statement

I'm trying to refactor some code that reads a csv file. The first character in every line of the file indicates the type of record: `H` = Header, `I` = Information, and `D` = Data. Each record type has a fixed and different number of fields. My program uses FasterCSV to read a line from the file and then uses a case statement to determine how to process the line.

```
     record_type = new_record[:record_type]
     case record_type
     when "H"
     factory_build_H_record(new_record)
     when "I"
     factory_build_I_record(new_record)
     when "D"
     factory_build_e_record(new_record)
     end
```

For refactoring, I'm trying to follow [Sandi Metz' blog post](http://sandimetz.com/2009/06/ruby-case-statements-and-kindof.html) on the use of case statements in OO programming and eliminate case statements. My inclination is that I need to create some classes that represent the three record types and then define some methods like `process_record`. I'm not sure how I should go about to create the classes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a fan of monkey patching core classes like that unless there's a real good reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case statements are not bad for small and fairly static conditional cases like the one you have.

If (theoretically) you anticipated having more record types in the future (besides H, I, and D), then the problem with the case statement is that it might cause you to start violating the [Open-Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

In this case, you might create a set of `RecordType` classes that is something along these lines:

```
class HeaderRecordType
  def is_mine(record)
     ...
  end
  def build(record)
     ...
  end
end

class DataRecordType
   ...
end

class SomeNewRecordType
   ...
end
```

Then, instead of the case, you would just iterate over a list of all the `RecordType`'s (or use a [Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_of_responsibility_pattern)) and ask each one `is_mine(record)`. As soon as one of them says yes, then you stop looking and call `build`.

Answer (score 1):

The blog post you linked is specifically about using `case` statements to tell what kind of object something is. That is often a symptom of bad design, and that is the point she is making.

The way you are using a `case` statement is much more acceptable. In fact, no matter how you restructure this, you are going to be doing some kind of test (`case`, or `if`, or otherwise) against that column in order to determine the correct behavior for the row.

If your code later on has to try to tell those objects apart by their class (using a case statement or if), then you are violating the spirit of the blog article.

The solution, is to create objects that have the same interface (have the same methods, used in the same way. The behavior of those methods is different internally in each class to do the right thing for that object.

Hope this helps clear up the concept for you :)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So are you saying my code is ok as is or that I need to create object that have the same interface - I believe this is called duck typing, yes?

Comment: It is called polymorphism.

Comment: You can keep that code if you like. The objects returned by `factory_build_H_record`, `factory_build_I_record`, should have similar interfaces, so you can use them in a uniform way later in the code.